# Triangle angle question

Tags: triangles

I need help about a triangle angle question.

Comment: Yes, but I could not figure out.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Answer (score 3):

Flip the whole image through the symmetry median of the $20-80-80$ triangle. The outer part forms a large equilateral triangle.

Construct a smaller equilateral triangle outside the $80-80$ edge.

[image: construction]

Find the reflective and rotational symmetry, and check that $\alpha$ is half of $20^\circ$.

---

Edit: changed diagram to name points

Comment: Not true. http://i.imgur.com/wZuEoN7.jpg

Comment: @blackcat52 I didn't say $\triangle ADC$ (in your image) is isosceles, nor say $\alpha = 20^\circ$.

Comment: The ADC in question, the angle of 140 degrees. If the DAC angle is 20, 20 degrees angle of DCA. Therefore, the ADC is isosceles.

Comment: @blackcat52 Again, it is NOT true, and I did NOT imply, that $\alpha = \angle DCA = 20^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

There is typically a clever trick to solving these problems, but if you do not know the trick you can always just throw coordinates at them.

Let $x$ be the length of the three equal-sized lines, and let the point at the bottom left be at ($0$,$0$).

The point at the top is then at ($x\cos(40^{\circ})$,$x\sin(40^{\circ})$).

The point at the bottom right is at ($2x\cos(20^{\circ})$,$0$)

so

$$\tan(20^{\circ}+\alpha) = \frac{x\sin(40^{\circ})}{2x\cos(20^{\circ}) - x\cos(40^{\circ})}$$

$$\tan(20^{\circ}+\alpha) = \frac{\sin(40^{\circ})}{2\cos(20^{\circ}) - \cos(40^{\circ})}$$

$$20^{\circ}+\alpha = \arctan\left( \frac{\sin(40^{\circ})}{2\cos(20^{\circ}) - \cos(40^{\circ})} \right)$$

The r.h.s. is [$30^{\circ}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan%28sin%2840%C2%B0%29%2F%282*cos%2820%C2%B0%29-cos%2840%C2%B0%29%29%29)

$$20^{\circ}+\alpha = 30^{\circ}$$

$$\alpha = 10^{\circ}$$